# TV show about a group of boys and magic

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic

I remember a show I watched in the 2000s about a group of boys and magic going on around them. One episode has them in a little cabin of some sorts and one character had bees or wasps flying around him. This is the best I can remember but as a kid I was very into the show. I think there was a book involved and there was once a tornado in the woods, where they were, and it took them to another universe, where none of this had happened.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Nowhere Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_Boys)* (2013-).

The show contains magic, bees and a scene where the characters travel through a swirly woodland portal thingy into a parallel universe.

Comment: Thank you very much Valorum! Thats the show i was looking for and i appreciate your help!

Comment: @OrionWesternburg - [Always a pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)